# How to create a JarJar'd artifact with Maven, where use of artifact does not pull transitive dependencies?

Tags: maven, classpath, software-distribution, artifact, jarjar

I currently have a Java testing library which is built with Maven, and distributed as a jar. My project depends on a very common library (Objectweb ASM), and I've experienced problems where an earlier and incompatible version of ASM is already on the classpath. Thus, I've started usings the [jarjar-maven-plugin](http://sonatype.github.com/jarjar-maven-plugin/) to create jar, repackaging ASM internally where it cannot conflict with another version of ASM.

This executes fine, and my library can be pulled in as a dependency with no problem.

However, because my project has compile-scope dependencies on ASM, whenever a client project adds my library, the transitive dependencies are all pulled in as well. So, hypothetically, if they use a particular version of ASM, and they also add the version I depend on to the classpath, they have undefined behaviour. I'd like to avoid this situation, and allow clients to depend on the JarJar'd artifact without having Maven pulling down the transitive dependencies both unnecessarily and potentially dangerously.

How do I create a JarJar'd artifact which users can depend on without pulling transitive dependencies?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem by ditching the jarjar-maven-plugin, and reverting to the maven-shade-plugin. This allows repackaging classes within your own namespace, setting the main class of the jar, and crucially, rewriting the generated pom to *not* include the compile time dependencies which are now bundled.

The part of my pom.xml which acheived this is:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.4</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>

            <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
            <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>

            <relocations>
                <relocation>
                    <pattern>org.objectweb.asm</pattern>
                    <shadedPattern>${repackage.base}.org.objectweb.asm</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
            </relocations>
            <transformers>
                <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                    <mainClass>${package.base}.my.MainClass</mainClass>
                </transformer>
            </transformers>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

The important parts of this configuration are:

- `shadedArtifactAttached` which when set to false, means the shaded jar will replace the main artifact that would normally be produced. This defaults to false but it's worth pointing out.
- `createDependencyReducedPom` which when set to true means that when the shaded jar is deployed or installed, the pom.xml which is deployed will not include the compile-scope dependencies which have been repackaged into the jar.
- `relocation` these elements configure how files within the dependencies are repackaged into the shaded jar. In the above example any class whose canonical name begins with `org.objectweb.asm` will be moved to `${package.base}.org.objectweb.asm`, and thus when packaged in the jar will have the equivalent file path within the jar.

With this configuration, when my project is deployed, when clients declare a compile-scope dependency on my project, it only pulls in the shaded jar, and no transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Consider trying the maven-shade-plugin instead, which allows all sorts of fine control.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps setting the `<optional>` attribute will work in your case.   Specifying something like the following in your java testing library pom.

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>asm.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>x.y</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
```